# mySQL Driver class not found in JDeveloper 11g

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, oracle11g, jdeveloper

In testing an existing Oracle SOA Composite using Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.7.0).  When I try to test one of the connections to the mySQL database I see this error: "Test failed: Driver class not found. Verify the Driver location".

I have added the mySQL Library in JDeveloper and pointed it to the JAR file as pointed out here:[JDeveloper MySQL error Driver not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314453/jdeveloper-mysql-error-driver-not-found)

I also ran through the steps to outline adding the JAR here:http://jdev11g.blogspot.com/2009/04/oracle-jdeveloper-11g-with-mysql.html

I have tried mapping the library to the JAR as well as moving the JAR under JDeveloper in C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\jdev\lib and mapping it there.

When I go to the Database Navigator and try to connect I get an Error encountered alert stating "An error was encountered performing the requested operation: Driver class not found. Verify the Driver location Vendor code 0."

Thanks,

Tom Henricksen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reading this blog post: http://www.jobinesh.com/2009/06/adf-with-mysql.html

I realized my mistake was the difference from Project Properties and Default Project Properties.  I had added the library to the wrong one.  They are both under the Application menu in JDeveloper 11G.

Thanks,

Tom